# Google Maps API in Ionic Framework

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

Im trying to implement a google maps inside of an Ionic List Card. From what I understand the card has a dynamic size depending on the content of the card. When I put my google maps inside of the list card and give a height of 100% its does not show. But if I give it a pixel size it appears just fine.

My maps html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Map">
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list card">

        <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img src="img/{{siteInfo.capitalName}}.png">
            <h2>{{Map.siteInfo.fullName}}</h2>
            <p>{{Map.siteInfo.fisicalDirection}}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" ng-click="Map.getDirections(pin)">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-location-outline"></i> Directions
        </a>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And a CSS of #map { height: 100%; }

EDIT:
How can I make the map show within the list card without having to give the map div a pixel height. So it can be dynamic when running in different devices.

Comment: Fine, but what's the actual question and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think,  It wants to undersand why the map is visible when It uses pixel(px)  and does not show when it uses percent(%).

Comment: I edited to reflect my question. @Franky I think it does not work with % since the list card also has dynamic height depending on the content.

Comment: This is a common hybrid mobile application question. Google Maps V3 API can't work in a container that don't have a real size. 100% will work only in case parent container has a real height, but a whole Ionic structure was made to be flexible. I will write you a working example.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hR0jBz?p=preview